# Where is a clear documentation about Windows API?

Tags: windows, api, winapi

Where Can I learn all the API of Windows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a complete reference online, I frequently turn to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663300(v=VS.85).aspx).

If you want a book, I would recommend [Petzold](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X) for WinAPI and [Prosise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572316950) for MFC.  Neither is cheap, and their publish dates are a little old, but they're both fantastic books.

Answer (score 8):

The [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663300.aspx) is generally considered as the canonical source for WinAPI development.

Answer (score 3):

IF i may propose a book, i propose you

Programming Windows by Charlse Petzold

http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/

the Charles Petzold's guide to windows programming, i think that is the ultimate guide to the Windows API